# Trying to get value from object using external url but

Tags: javascript, json, discord.js

When i start bot console say:

```
Online with undefined/5
```

and when 10 secconds are passed give this error:

**undefined:1
[object Promise]
^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1**

My Code:

```
let jogadores
client.on("ready", async () => {

async function players_online() {
    const response = fetch(`http://ip:port/dynamic.json`);
    const data = JSON.parse(response);
    jogadores = data.clients;


}

async function autoconnect() {

    if (jogadores === -1) {
        console.log('Offline');

    } else {
        console.log('Online with ' + jogadores + '/5')

    }
}
autoconnect()

setInterval(() => {
    client.user.setStatus('dnd');
    client.user.setActivity(`Online with ${jogadores} players.`, { type: 'PLAYING' })
    players_online()
}, 10000)

})
```

Comment: you need to await the call to fetch. try `await fetch()`

Answer (score 0):

You have quite some problems with your code. I will list them below:

#### Required fixes

- As [@about14sheep](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9583747/about14sheep) said, you must use `await` to get the actual response.
- You are not supposed to use `JSON.parse()` on a response, but rather `response.json()` to get the JSON body.
- Use of an incorrect operator, for numbers I'd suggest you use `==` than `===`
- Before 10 seconds have passed, it will show undefined. To fix this, call the function before the `setInterval()`.

#### Optional things I added

- Formatted JS code
- Added semicolons when necessary
- Used ES6 template literals feature
- Removed async when un-needed

I have fixed all of these problems in the code below.

```js
let jogadores;

client.on('ready', async () => {

    async function players_online() {
        const response = await fetch(`http://ip:port/dynamic.json`);
        const data = await response.json();
        jogadores = data.clients;
    }

    function autoconnect() {
        if (jogadores == -1) {
            console.log('Offline');
        } else {
            console.log(`Online with ${jogadores}/5`);
        }
    }

    autoconnect();
    players_online();

    setInterval(() => {
        client.user.setStatus('dnd');
        client.user.setActivity(`Online with ${jogadores} players.`, {
            type: 'PLAYING'
        });
    }, 10000);

});
```